# find all intersections of two curves(non-fuctions)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I found similar questions like this topic to find all intersection of 2 curves[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541080/python-find-all-intersection-points-of-2-graphs)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604802/python-finding-an-element-in-an-array), In all of them we have functions, but what if we want to find these crossing points for non-functions curves? Here is an example:

[image]
[image]

to plot I wrote:

```
plt.plot(Enull,x, '-',label='E nullcline') 
plt.plot(x,Inull, '-',label='I nullcline')
```

I replaced `I` in `E` to have a one-variable function, then I used  `fzero` to find the  intersections. If I have the approximate value of `E` say : 
`cross = np.array([0.05,0.1,0.45])` , the problem is solved.
So the question is how to find these approximate values of crossing?
Thanks for any guide.

[python code in my dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21031944/Stack/stack.py)

Comment: if I rotate the figure it is a function. then it's enough to subtract two cures. Here two curves don't have the same x values(if we take the vertical axes as x) for each x value I should find corresponding y value(horizontal axis as y). programming become a little awkward.I think there should be a better way.