# Find the intersection of two curves given by (x, y) data with high precision in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, scipy

I have two datasets: (x, y1) and (x, y2). I'd like to find the location where these two curves cross one another. The goal is similar to this question: [Intersection of two graphs in Python, find the x value:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766692/intersection-of-two-graphs-in-python-find-the-x-value)

However, the method described there only finds the intersection to the nearest data-point. I would like to find the intersection of the curves with higher precision than the original data spacing. One option is to simply re-interpolate to a finer grid. This works, but then the precision is determined by the number of points that I choose for the re-interpolation, which is arbitrary, and requires a tradeoff between precision and efficiency.

Alternatively, I could use `scipy.optimize.fsolve` to find the exact intersection of the two spline interpolations of the data-sets. This works well, but it cannot easily find multiple intersection points, requires that I provide a reasonable guess for the intersection point, and probably does not scale well. (Ultimately, I would like to find the intersection of several thousand sets of (x, y1, y2), so an efficient algorithm would be nice.)

Here is what I have so far. Any ideas for improvement?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate, scipy.optimize

x  = np.linspace(1, 4, 20)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = 0.05*x

plt.plot(x, y1, marker='o', mec='none', ms=4, lw=1, label='y1')
plt.plot(x, y2, marker='o', mec='none', ms=4, lw=1, label='y2')

idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(y1 - y2)) != 0)

plt.plot(x[idx], y1[idx], 'ms', ms=7, label='Nearest data-point method')

interp1 = scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y1)
interp2 = scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y2)

new_x = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
new_y1 = interp1(new_x)
new_y2 = interp2(new_x)
idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(new_y1 - new_y2)) != 0)
plt.plot(new_x[idx], new_y1[idx], 'ro', ms=7, label='Nearest data-point method, with re-interpolated data')

def difference(x):
    return np.abs(interp1(x) - interp2(x))

x_at_crossing = scipy.optimize.fsolve(difference, x0=3.0)
plt.plot(x_at_crossing, interp1(x_at_crossing), 'cd', ms=7, label='fsolve method')

plt.legend(frameon=False, fontsize=10, numpoints=1, loc='lower left')

plt.savefig('curve crossing.png', dpi=200)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't there always a trade-off between accuracy and efficiency? You could continue to interpolate to a finer mesh until your answer converges to within a tolerable amount.

Comment: Isn't the approximate information from the grid intersection exactly what you need to set up the spline intersection problem? The only problem I can see would be if you had multiple intersections within a single grid cell. I would run the grid intersection and then use the answers from that to solve the spline intersection, using splines restricted to the few cells near the grid intersection found.

Comment: waterboy5281, I suppose you are right, that there is typically a trade-off between efficiency and precision, given the same algorithm. However, a better algorithm is often both faster and more precise.
@mcdowella, I like the idea of finding the approximate position of the intersection via the "nearest data point" method, and then using this information to make it easier to find the precise crossing point. I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best (and most efficient) answer will likely depend on the datasets and how they are sampled. But, a good approximation for many datasets is that they are nearly linear between the datapoints. So, we can find the approximate position of the intersection by the "nearest datapoint" method shown in the original post. Then, we can refine the position of the intersection between the nearest two data points using linear interpolation.

This method is pretty fast, and works with 2D numpy arrays, in case you want to calculate the crossing of multiple curves at once (as I want to do in my application).

(I borrowed code from "[How do I compute the intersection point of two lines in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677795/how-do-i-compute-the-intersection-point-of-two-lines-in-python)" for the linear interpolation.)

```
from __future__ import division 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def interpolated_intercept(x, y1, y2):
    """Find the intercept of two curves, given by the same x data"""

    def intercept(point1, point2, point3, point4):
        """find the intersection between two lines
        the first line is defined by the line between point1 and point2
        the first line is defined by the line between point3 and point4
        each point is an (x,y) tuple.

        So, for example, you can find the intersection between
        intercept((0,0), (1,1), (0,1), (1,0)) = (0.5, 0.5)

        Returns: the intercept, in (x,y) format
        """    

        def line(p1, p2):
            A = (p1[1] - p2[1])
            B = (p2[0] - p1[0])
            C = (p1[0]*p2[1] - p2[0]*p1[1])
            return A, B, -C

        def intersection(L1, L2):
            D  = L1[0] * L2[1] - L1[1] * L2[0]
            Dx = L1[2] * L2[1] - L1[1] * L2[2]
            Dy = L1[0] * L2[2] - L1[2] * L2[0]

            x = Dx / D
            y = Dy / D
            return x,y

        L1 = line([point1[0],point1[1]], [point2[0],point2[1]])
        L2 = line([point3[0],point3[1]], [point4[0],point4[1]])

        R = intersection(L1, L2)

        return R

    idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(y1 - y2)) != 0)
    xc, yc = intercept((x[idx], y1[idx]),((x[idx+1], y1[idx+1])), ((x[idx], y2[idx])), ((x[idx+1], y2[idx+1])))
    return xc,yc

def main():
    x  = np.linspace(1, 4, 20)
    y1 = np.sin(x)
    y2 = 0.05*x

    plt.plot(x, y1, marker='o', mec='none', ms=4, lw=1, label='y1')
    plt.plot(x, y2, marker='o', mec='none', ms=4, lw=1, label='y2')

    idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(y1 - y2)) != 0)

    plt.plot(x[idx], y1[idx], 'ms', ms=7, label='Nearest data-point method')

    # new method!
    xc, yc = interpolated_intercept(x,y1,y2)
    plt.plot(xc, yc, 'co', ms=5, label='Nearest data-point, with linear interpolation')


    plt.legend(frameon=False, fontsize=10, numpoints=1, loc='lower left')

    plt.savefig('curve crossing.png', dpi=200)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

[image: Curve crossing]

**Update 2018-12-13**:
If it is necessary to find several intercepts, here is a modified version of the code that does that:

```
from __future__ import division 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def interpolated_intercepts(x, y1, y2):
    """Find the intercepts of two curves, given by the same x data"""

    def intercept(point1, point2, point3, point4):
        """find the intersection between two lines
        the first line is defined by the line between point1 and point2
        the first line is defined by the line between point3 and point4
        each point is an (x,y) tuple.

        So, for example, you can find the intersection between
        intercept((0,0), (1,1), (0,1), (1,0)) = (0.5, 0.5)

        Returns: the intercept, in (x,y) format
        """    

        def line(p1, p2):
            A = (p1[1] - p2[1])
            B = (p2[0] - p1[0])
            C = (p1[0]*p2[1] - p2[0]*p1[1])
            return A, B, -C

        def intersection(L1, L2):
            D  = L1[0] * L2[1] - L1[1] * L2[0]
            Dx = L1[2] * L2[1] - L1[1] * L2[2]
            Dy = L1[0] * L2[2] - L1[2] * L2[0]

            x = Dx / D
            y = Dy / D
            return x,y

        L1 = line([point1[0],point1[1]], [point2[0],point2[1]])
        L2 = line([point3[0],point3[1]], [point4[0],point4[1]])

        R = intersection(L1, L2)

        return R

    idxs = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(y1 - y2)) != 0)

    xcs = []
    ycs = []

    for idx in idxs:
        xc, yc = intercept((x[idx], y1[idx]),((x[idx+1], y1[idx+1])), ((x[idx], y2[idx])), ((x[idx+1], y2[idx+1])))
        xcs.append(xc)
        ycs.append(yc)
    return np.array(xcs), np.array(ycs)

def main():
    x  = np.linspace(1, 10, 50)
    y1 = np.sin(x)
    y2 = 0.02*x

    plt.plot(x, y1, marker='o', mec='none', ms=4, lw=1, label='y1')
    plt.plot(x, y2, marker='o', mec='none', ms=4, lw=1, label='y2')

    idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(y1 - y2)) != 0)

    plt.plot(x[idx], y1[idx], 'ms', ms=7, label='Nearest data-point method')

    # new method!
    xcs, ycs = interpolated_intercepts(x,y1,y2)
    for xc, yc in zip(xcs, ycs):
        plt.plot(xc, yc, 'co', ms=5, label='Nearest data-point, with linear interpolation')


    plt.legend(frameon=False, fontsize=10, numpoints=1, loc='lower left')

    plt.savefig('curve crossing.png', dpi=200)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

```
[image]

Comment: See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909373/how-to-find-the-exact-intersection-of-a-curve-as-np-array-with-y-0/46911822#46911822) using `np.diff` and  `np.interp` to find the intersection between curves.