# How to find the exact intersection of a curve (as np.array) with y==0?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph

How can I get from a plot in Python an exact value on *y* - axis? I have two arrays `vertical_data` and `gradient(temperature_data)` and I plotted them as:

```
plt.plot(gradient(temperature_data),vertical_data)
plt.show()
```

Plot shown here:

[image: plot]

I need the zero value but it is not exactly zero, it's a float.

Comment: I guess the problem description is a bit misleading, if present at all. What you want is to find the zero of a numpy array. This has nothing to do with matplotlib. (Also there are more than one zero). This is in general a non-trivial task. But depending on the accuracy needed, can be simplified.

Comment: Well I should see it in that plotted graph, I think

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I did not find a good answer to the question of how to find the roots or zeros of a numpy array, so here is a solution, using simple linear interpolation.

```
import numpy as np
N = 750
x = .4+np.sort(np.random.rand(N))*3.5
y = (x-4)*np.cos(x*9.)*np.cos(x*6+0.05)+0.1


def find_roots(x,y):
    s = np.abs(np.diff(np.sign(y))).astype(bool)
    return x[:-1][s] + np.diff(x)[s]/(np.abs(y[1:][s]/y[:-1][s])+1)

z = find_roots(x,y)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(z, np.zeros(len(z)), marker="o", ls="", ms=4)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Of course you can invert the roles of `x` and `y` to get

```
plt.plot(y,x)
plt.plot(np.zeros(len(z)),z, marker="o", ls="", ms=4)
```

[image]

---

Because people where asking how to get the intercepts at non-zero values `y0`, note that one may simply find the zeros of `y-y0` then.

```
y0 = 1.4
z = find_roots(x,y-y0)
# ...
plt.plot(z, np.zeros(len(z))+y0)
```

[image]

---

People were also asking how to get the intersection between *two* curves. In that case it's again about finding the roots of the difference between the two, e.g.

```
x = .4 + np.sort(np.random.rand(N)) * 3.5
y1 = (x - 4) * np.cos(x * 9.) * np.cos(x * 6 + 0.05) + 0.1
y2 = (x - 2) * np.cos(x * 8.) * np.cos(x * 5 + 0.03) + 0.3

z = find_roots(x,y2-y1)

plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.plot(x,y2, color="C2")
plt.plot(z, np.interp(z, x, y1), marker="o", ls="", ms=4, color="C1")
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, just wanted to say that's a neat idea to turn places where the sign of the function changes sign into indices like this. Thanks!

Comment: @JohanC For regularly spaced data one could replace `np.diff(x)[s]` by `(x[1]-x[0])`. That would give a very small performance gain, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Why the last "+1" in `return x[:-1][s] + np.diff(x)[s]/(np.abs(y[1:][s]/y[:-1][s])+1)`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Brilliant and elegant! Do you have a ref for the equation used / LaTeX version? :)

Comment: Also, not that it probably matters, but how (i) expensive and (ii) accurate (as in second-order residuals) is this compared to other methods? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Also also, could you use it iteratively and if so how would you yourself tackle it?

Comment: Re REF,  e.g. one of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms / Numerical Recipes?

Comment: PS: Even handles `x.dtype` of `datetime` - amazing!

Comment: Also, how would you handle only the rising (or falling) edges?

Comment: @jtlz2 for posterity, rising edges can be selectively handled with `s = np.abs(np.maximum(np.diff(np.sign(y)), 0)).astype(bool)`. Same goes for falling edges with `np.minimum`.