# How to get X-coordinate of Path depending on the Y-coordinate when X-coordinate values are unknown using python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

How I can get a point on the curve plotting when I have only one known Y-coordinate equation i.e. P = a * b (where a & b are defined values say 0.8,150) and x-coordinate is totally unknown and there is no equation linking x and y ( ex: y = mx +b; # i don't have this kind of equations). So, now the target is if say I have 'Y-coordinate' value as 120 and need to plot a point on the curve by taking distance or path from the unknown 'x-coordiante' value.

I tried the code as below

[One sample figure about how I should plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJQ4p.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

# given values
y = np.array([0, 38.39, 71.41, 99.66, 123.67, 143.88, 160.61, 174.03, 184.16, 190.8, 193.52])
x = np.array([0, 0.37, 0.74, 1.11, 1.48, 1.85, 2.22, 2.59, 2.96, 3.33, 3.7])
x_val = np.linspace(0,7) #limts on x-axis
a = 0.8
b = 150
y_val = np.multiply(a, b)
yinterp = np.interp(x_val, x, y)
plt.plot(x, y, '-')
plt.plot(x_val, yinterp, 'o')

#here i need to plot a exact point w.r.t to y_val
#and also need to show the distance with a line from the selected x and y coordinates

plt.plot(x_val,y_val, '--') 
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve, but you will probably need to use something like `np.interp(y_val, y, x)`.

Comment: @kazemakase thanks for the reply, my aim is to plot a point on a curve when i know the y-intercept say (0,120) but i don't know x-intercept values.Now I need to find the x-intercept points by using y-intercept. You can also see the image attached.

Comment: I don't know what an intercept is (in this case) but the code in my comment above returns the interpolated x that corresponds to `y_val`, which seems to be what you are after...

Comment: Yes the code you written in comment is working but my aim is to get only one point on the curve w.r.t. Y value and in my case the y-intercept value to be taken as(0,y_val). I only need to plot one point on x-axis by using y_value

Answer (score 4):

What you want is to find the root(s) or zero(s) of an array. This question's answer shows how to do that: [How to get values from a graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909373/how-to-get-values-from-a-graph)

Applying the solution to this case here would look as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# given values
y = np.array([0, 38.39, 71.41, 99.66, 123.67, 143.88, 160.61, 174.03, 184.16, 190.8, 193.52])
x = np.array([0, 0.37, 0.74, 1.11, 1.48, 1.85, 2.22, 2.59, 2.96, 3.33, 3.7])
x_val = np.linspace(0,7) 

plt.plot(x, y, '-')

def find_roots(x,y):
    s = np.abs(np.diff(np.sign(y))).astype(bool)
    return x[:-1][s] + np.diff(x)[s]/(np.abs(y[1:][s]/y[:-1][s])+1)

a = 0.8
b = 150
y_val = np.multiply(a, b)

roots = find_roots(x, y-y_val)
plt.plot(roots[0],y_val, marker="o") 
plt.plot([roots[0],roots[0],0],[0,y_val,y_val], "--")

plt.xlim(0,None)
plt.ylim(0,None)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If the arrays are monotonically increasing, you may of course also simply interpolate:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# given values
y = np.array([0, 38.39, 71.41, 99.66, 123.67, 143.88, 160.61, 174.03, 184.16, 190.8, 193.52])
x = np.array([0, 0.37, 0.74, 1.11, 1.48, 1.85, 2.22, 2.59, 2.96, 3.33, 3.7])
x_val = np.linspace(0,7) 

plt.plot(x, y, '-')

a = 0.8
b = 150
y_val = np.multiply(a, b)

root = np.interp(y_val,y,x)
plt.plot(root,y_val, marker="o") 
plt.plot([root,root,0],[0,y_val,y_val], "--")

plt.xlim(0,None)
plt.ylim(0,None)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks alot this is what exactly I needed and may I know for this can I take the x,y points as a csv file rather than entering all points.

Comment: Yes that is sure possible.

Comment: for the same question may I know how I can plot if I have a CSV file as attached to the question where there are 3 columns in which x and y columns are used to plot the line and z column is used to group the x and y columns to get multiple lines.

Comment: I am successful in applying csv files but I need help in finding the roots when x_val is given but y_val is unkown, reverese of above case may I know what factors i need to change in the below equation do i need to inter change x with y  :                                                                                                               s = np.abs(np.diff(np.sign(y))).astype(bool)
return x[:-1][s] + np.diff(x)[s]/(np.abs(y[1:][s]/y[:-1][s])+1

Comment: So, first of all, my solution may have been a bit too complicated for this simple case, so I updated the answer. For doing the inverse, you just change the role of y and x.

Comment: Great!! but I am getting an error saying  "array of sample points is empty" for the below lines(I coverted  it as array  to avoid error but still the same error is repeated) :    semi_unrein_sig_min is the variable  :-                                                                                                    y_min = np.asarray(semi_unrein_sig_min,dtype=float) ;
                                                                                                           x_min = np.interp(y_min,y,x)

Comment: Most of the times, python errors really directly tell you the problem. In this case, either `x` or `y` or both are empty. I hope you don't expect me to know what you did for that to happen.

Comment: my x and y points are also in array:-  x=np.asarray(gdf.index.values);
y=np.asarray(gdf['y'].values)