# Determine intercepts of noisy data with constant

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Is it possible to determine all intercepts of noisy data and a constant value?

I am working on a project with a sensitive probe and need to know when my data drops below a certain limit.

You could compare my data with this random result:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

noise = np.random.normal(1, 2, 50)
x = np.arange(0, 50)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, noise, '-')
ax.axhline(1, color='r')
```

[image: Example curve]

I already tried the scipy.interpolate.interp1d function as a possible solution but this doesn't seem to be the correct approach towards this issue.
Is there a way to find these intercepts?

Comment: Do you mean how to get the roots/zeros of an array like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909373/how-to-get-values-from-a-graph)?

Comment: Indeed, this resembles my problem, but instead of the intercepts with 0 I am looking for the intercepts with a constant number (eg. 1)

Comment: Well, it might not be obvious, so I added a section about it in the answer over there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a relatively simple solution, but works perfect!