# Seaborn: how to draw a vertical line that matches a specific y value in a cumulative KDE?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, distribution

I'm using Seaborn to plot a cumulative distribution and it's KDE using this code:

```
sns.distplot(values, bins=20, 
             hist_kws= {'cumulative': True}, 
             kde_kws= {'cumulative': True} )
```

This gives me the following chart:

[image: Cumulative distribution and kde]

I'd like to plot a vertical line and the corresponding x index where y is 0.8. Something like:

[image: KDE with vertical line]

How do I get the x value of a specific y?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update for newer Seaborn versions, with sns.histplot

The code below has been tested with Seaborn 0.13.2. The 0.8 quantile is calculated and shown as an annotated vertical line.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

values = np.random.normal(1, 20, 1000)
ax = sns.histplot(values, bins=20, cumulative=True, kde=True, color='salmon')
perc = 80
x80 = np.quantile(values, perc / 100)
ax.axvline(x80, color='b')
ax.text(x80, 0.98, f"{perc}th percentile: \nx={x80:.2f} ", color='b',
        ha='right', va='top', transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform())
ax.margins(x=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: cumulative sns.histplot with 80th percentile]

## Old answer

You could draw a vertical line at the 80% quantile:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

values = np.random.normal(1, 20, 1000)
sns.distplot(values, bins=20,
             hist_kws= {'cumulative': True},
             kde_kws= {'cumulative': True} )
plt.axvline(np.quantile(values, 0.8), color='r')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Nice and clear solution. You can annotate the line with the label: `line = ax.axvline(x, color='r')
    
    ax.annotate(f'{x:.0f}', 
                xy=(x,0), xytext=(0,-14), color=line.get_color(), 
                xycoords = ax.get_xaxis_transform(), textcoords="offset points",
                size=12, ha="center")`

Answer (score 3):

The [answer by @JohanC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62996261/1356000) is probably the best. I went an other route and it's maybe a slightly more generic solution.

The idea is to get the coordinates of the kde line, then find the indice of the point where it crosses the threshold value

```
values = np.random.normal(size=(100,))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = sns.distplot(values, bins=20, 
             hist_kws= {'cumulative': True}, 
             kde_kws= {'cumulative': True} )

x,y = ax.lines[0].get_data()
thresh = 0.8
idx = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(y-thresh)))[0]
x_val = x[idx[0]]
ax.axvline(x_val, color='red')
```

[image]

Comment: The answer can be improved further to find the exact interpolated x value as in [this magic post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909373/how-to-find-the-exact-intersection-of-a-curve-as-np-array-with-y-0/46911822#46911822).

Comment: I select @JohanC answer because it is simpler, but this answer is also excellent. This one can be more efficient since it isn't necessary to reprocess the histogram. I also liked that it gives an interpolated value instead of one that is present in the population.