# Intersecting two graphs with matplotlib and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graphics

I created a graphic calculator with numpy and matplotlib. It asks the user how many graphs he wants to draw. Then it accepts that much input by using a for loop. Then it draws the graphs with the same loop. The problem is how can I intersect these graphs, and put a point or something to the intersection? Can someone please help me with that? Also, I am new to this area, so you might see some terrible mistakes? Sorry for that :)

```
        print("How many equations do you want to draw: ")
        numofeq = input()
        r1= int(input("Enter range-1: "))
        r2= int(input("Enter range-2: "))

        for i in range(int(numofeq)): 
            print("Equation")
            eq = input()
            x = np.array(range(int(r1), int(r2+1)))
            y = eval(bytes([ord(p) for p in eq]))
            plt.plot(x, y)

            

        ax = plt.gca()
        ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
        ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
        ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
        ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: The title should have been two or more. But, if someone helps me with two, I can deal with the rest. : )

Comment: Please note that posting code (or data) as image instead of as text is seen very very badly at stackoverflow.

Comment: This undervalued post shows how to intersect two curves.   [How to find the exact intersection of a curve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46911822/12046409)

Comment: @JohanC, sorry. I'm also new to stackoverflow. : )

Comment: Well, you are supposed to edit your post, delete the image and copy-paste the code.

Comment: Well, is it okay now?