# How to project the intersection point of a plot with a line?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am looking for a way to project the intersection point of the graph using a vertical discontinuous line (style '--') on the x-axis and then write the x-coordinate on that axis.

Here's my attempt to find the intersection. For some reason, the point is not exactly on the intersection. It's strange.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

n = 256 
k = np.arange(0, 100) 
g = 1 - np.exp(-0.5 * k * (k - 1) / n)
plt.plot(g, '-')
plt.hlines(0.5, 0, 100, 'r')
idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(g - 0.5)))
plt.plot(k[idx], g[idx], 'o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You might start with finding the intersection, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766692/intersection-of-two-graphs-in-python-find-the-x-value, then think about drawing it.

Comment: I did it and edited my post. It looks strange.

Comment: For your particular equation, 100 data points isn't enough "resolution" to have an index where the value falls exactly on the intersection point.

Comment: [How to find the exact intersection of a curve (as np.array) with y==0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46911822/12046409) provides a way to find the exact intersection point using linear interpolation. You can call `find_roots(k, g-0,5)` using the function of the linked post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by tevemadar you need to find the intersection point by solving for k for g = 0.5 i.e where you've drawn your hline.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

n = 256
k = np.arange(0, 100)
f = 0.5
g = 1 - np.exp(-0.5 * k * (k - 1) / n)
plt.plot(g, '-')

hline_pos = 0.5
plt.hlines(hline_pos, 0, 100, 'r')
# inverse
# np.exp(-0.5 * k * (k - 1) / n) = 1 - g
# -0.5 * k * (k - 1) / n = np.log(1 - g)
# k^2 - k = np.log(1 - g) * (-n/0.5)
solve_for = hline_pos
constant = np.log(1 - solve_for) * (-n/0.5)
ks = np.roots([1, -1, -constant])
ks = np.sort(ks) # sort to get the positive root based on the domain boundaries

plt.scatter(ks[1], hline_pos)
plt.vlines(ks[1], 0, hline_pos, linestyles='--')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If you zoom in, this solution is still broken, even if the intersect line seems to point at 0.5: https://i.imgur.com/rr4sTvQ.png

Comment: @AKX is ther a way to fix it?

Comment: it is only a approximate solution, will update soon.