# Find x value for respective y from python plot (matplotlib)

Tags: python, function, numpy, matplotlib

i know that we can find y values with numpy fonction as follows :

```
import numpy as np
x = [0.01474926, 0.96923077, 1]
y = [1, 0.7875, 0]
np.interp(0.75, x,y)
```

But I'd like to know if there's a way to find the x's for a respective y instead?

Thank you for the help

Comment: You can convert that to a minimization problem by subtracting y.... Then you can solve it with `scipy.optimize.root`

Comment: See `z = find_roots(x,y-y0)` in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46911822/12046409)