# matplotlib.patches.Arc and using the clip_path parameter

Tags: python, matplotlib, clip-path

I want to use in matplotlib.patches.Arc the clip_path parameter, but do not succeed.
Next is just an example, where I want to see not the complete orange arc but only the partial orange arc between y-axis and the red circle by using the clip_path parameter, but do no understand how to define the clip_path parameters. Thanks.

```
import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as pat

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10),dpi=300)

ag=10
plt.axis([-ag,ag,-ag,ag])  
plt.grid(True)

circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 2.5), 7, color='r',fill=False)
plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(circle1)   

myarc=pat.Arc((0,0),25,18,angle=0,theta1=0,theta2=355,color="orange")
plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(myarc) 

plt.savefig("myarc.png")
plt.show()
```

This is what I got:

[image]

Just a further remark: With next modification of theta1 and theta2 angle I get what I need, but for this the two intersections need to be determined first. My intention is to avoid these calculations and just draw an ellipse and defining two clipping paths (the red circle and the y-axis).

myarc=pat.Arc((0,0),25,18,angle=0,theta1=110,theta2=152,color="orange")

Comment: [Find the intersection of two curves given by (x, y) data with high precision in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464334/find-the-intersection-of-two-curves-given-by-x-y-data-with-high-precision-in) I find this answer to be very helpful

Comment: Thank you, this will work, determine the intersections and just draw the partial elliptical arc. But would like to avoid these calculations and let python find the intersections by defining the clip_path, if this works...

Comment: Matplotlib's clipping only seems to let you keep the inside, Probably you need a library such as [shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) for more elaborate clipping.

Comment: @JohanC   Thank you, I will check it. To get the orange arc inside the red circle, do you know the command syntax for this in the clip_path(???) option? I failed so far with defining any function in the clip_path.

Answer (score 2):

To clip the arc by the circle, you can use `myarc.set_clip_path(circle1)`. It is important that both the arc and the circle are previously added to the plot (`ax.add_artist()`). Note that clipping by the borders of the axes happens automatically.

To create more complicated clipping, the [shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) is probably handier.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 2.5), 7, color='r', fill=False)
ax.add_artist(circle1)

myarc = mpatches.Arc((0, 0), 25, 18, angle=0, theta1=0, theta2=355, color="orange", lw=5)
ax.add_artist(myarc)
myarc.set_clip_path(circle1)

ag = 10
ax.set_xlim(-ag, ag)
ax.set_ylim(-ag, ag)
plt.grid(True)
ax.set_aspect('equal') # set the aspect ratio so circles look like circles
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I copied your code lines, executed in Spyder 3.8 and got a plot with almost the complete orange ellipse, just on the right side beyond the grid the ellipse was cut off. Verified the copied code lines, see no difference...

Comment: Did you first add both the circle and the arc to the same `ax`?  `set_clip_path` only has the effect after the elements have been added. Maybe you could edit your question and add your new code?

Comment: Used your code above, copied it, tried ax.add_patch(myarc) as well, get always the red circle and the orange ellipse in and outside the red circle

Comment: Maybe you're not working with a recent matplotlib version?

Comment: just to provide the current status, I am still troubleshooting. My installation is Spyder 4.1.4, Python 3.8.3  64-bit | Qt 5.9.7 | PyQt5 5.9.2 | Windows 10 , matplotlib 3.2.2 and update check says, that Spyder is up to date.

Comment: Well, after Reset Spyder to factory defaults I get now the same plot as shown in your answer. Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

By using the steps of answer (1) I got the wanted result without the need to calculate all the intersections.  Steps:

1. Defining and Plotting series of curves
2. Defining clipping areas by using clip_path option (e.g. circles or shaping an area by concatenating 1D-arrays through mathematical function results)
3. Using clip_path to get rid of unwanted portion of curves

   ```
   # Import python Modules
   import math as m
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import numpy as np
   from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

   ## constants for the circles
   Loc=37      # in degree
   StepAl=3    # in degree
   StepAz=10   # in degree
   rAequ=6.3   # Radius
   rWkSt=9.6   # Radius
   Ze=3.14     # Distance

   ## red AlCircles, in total 31
   AlCircle=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
   i=0
   while i<=30:
       AlCircle[i]=[0,0,0,0]
       i=i+1   
   # Calculating the parameters of the AlCircles
   i=0
   while i<=30:
       AlCircle[i][0]=rAequ*m.tan((-Loc+i*StepAl)/2/180*m.pi)        # lower y-Value 
       AlCircle[i][1]=rAequ*m.tan((-Loc+180-i*StepAl)/2/180*m.pi)    # upper y-Value
       AlCircle[i][2]=(AlCircle[i][1]-AlCircle[i][0])/2    # Radius
       AlCircle[i][3]=AlCircle[i][0]+AlCircle[i][2]        # Center
       i=i+1

   ## green AzCircles, in total 18
   DZ=rAequ/m.cos(Loc/180*m.pi)    # Distance

   AzCircle=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
   i=0
   while i<=17:
       AzCircle[i]=[0,0]
       i=i+1   
   # Calculating the parameters of the AzCircles
   i=1
   while i<=17:
       AzCircle[i][0]=DZ*m.tan((-90+i*StepAz)/180*m.pi)  # distance Center to y-Axis
       AzCircle[i][1]=rAequ/m.cos(Loc/180*m.pi)/m.cos((-90+i*StepAz)/180*m.pi)    # Radius of AzCircles
       i=i+1   

   ### Generating Plots
   plt.figure(figsize=(10,10),dpi=100) 
   ag=rWkSt

   plt.axis([-ag,ag,-ag,ag])  
   plt.grid(True)

   # Plotting blue Circle
   circle0=plt.Circle((0,0),rWkSt,color='b',fill=False)
   plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(circle0)

   # Plotting red AlCircles
   i=0
   while i<=30:
       # defining Cliparea1
       myCliparea1=plt.Circle((0,0),rWkSt,color="b",ls="dotted",fill=False)
       plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(myCliparea1)

       # calculating AlCircles and plotting
       circle1=plt.Circle((0,AlCircle[i][3]),AlCircle[i][2],color='r',fill=False)
       plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(circle1)    

       circle1.set_clip_path(myCliparea1)   # performing clipping

       i=i+1

   # Plotting green AzCircles
   i=1
   while i<=17:   # nur bis 17
       xA=9.072582     # precalculated Intersection for f1(x) and f2(x)  

       # f1(x) for lower clipping area border line
       x1=np.arange(-xA,+xA,0.1)
       y1=(-1)*np.sqrt(AlCircle[0][2]**2-x1**2)+AlCircle[0][3]

       # f2(x) for upper clipping area border line
       x2=np.arange(xA,-xA,-0.1)
       y2=(+1)*np.sqrt(rWkSt**2-x2**2)

       # building clipping area
       x3=np.concatenate((x1,x2))
       y3=np.concatenate((y1,y2))
       poly = Polygon(np.column_stack([x3, y3]), animated=True, color="aqua", fill=False)
       plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(poly)       # plotting of clipping area

       # calculating AzCircles and plotting
       circle2=plt.Circle((-AzCircle[i][0],Ze-DZ),AzCircle[i][1],color='g',fill=False)
       plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(circle2)     

       circle2.set_clip_path(poly)    # performing clipping

       i=i+1    


   plt.savefig("myPlot.png")
   plt.show()
   ```

[myPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ2P8.png)

[image]