# How can I change the x-axis index date format in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

My code below outputs the following image:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import os

start = dt(2017, 1, 1)
end = dt.now()

df = web.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start, end, interval = 'd')
df['30_sma'] = df['Adj Close'].rolling(window=30, 
min_periods=None).mean()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(df.index, df['Adj Close'])
ax.plot(df.index, df['30_sma'])
plt.show()
```

[image: AAPL stock price, bad date format]

I would like the date to show up as YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM format. I have tried creating a new column in my data frame made up of the index, but that did not change anything when I plotted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work by calling `df.plot` and passing `ax` as a parameter -

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

df[['Adj Close', '30_sma']].plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @COLDSPEED this works for me, but is there any way to change colors/line types of individual lines?

Comment: @NaN I guess, you could pass a list to `styles`. Example - `df[['Adj Close', '30_sma']].plot(ax=ax, style=['r*-','bo-'])`

Comment: @NaN Thanks for accepting! You can also vote on the answer if you liked it. Thanks.

Comment: @COLDSPEED No problem, could you help me with one more thing I realized so I don't have to ask a separate question? I would like to add markers where the 30_sma crosses the Adj Close (e.g. green or red circles), is this possible?

Comment: @NaN Ah, my knowledge of matplotlib is very surface level... but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766692/intersection-of-two-graphs-in-python-find-the-x-value