# How to use SymPy to find the point of intersection of two functions?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I am trying to use the SymPy library to find the point of intersection(s) between two functions:

`f(x) = e ^ (x / 2)` and `g(x) = 3 - 3 * x`

I tried:

```
import sympy as syp

x = syp.symbols('x')

f_x = syp.E ** (x / 2)
g_x = 3 - 3 * x

print(syp.nsolve(f_x, g_x, x))
```

`syp.nsolve(f_x, g_x, x)` spits out a `TypeError`. Replacing that line with `syp.solve([f_x, g_x], x)` results in an empty list `[]`. This is wrong because `f(x)` and `g(x)` intersect at exactly one point.

How do I get the x and y values of the point of intersection(s) between any f(x) and g(x) using SymPy?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766692/intersection-of-two-graphs-in-python-find-the-x-value ?

Answer (score -1):

```
import sympy as syp

x = syp.symbols('x')

f_x = syp.E ** (x / 2)
g_x = 3 - 3 * x

print(syp.solve(f_x - g_x, x))
```

---

The output of the above code is:

```
[-2*LambertW(exp(1/2)/6) + 1]
```