# Inersection between dataframe graph and numpy graph

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to get the intersection between a dataframe graph and a numpy graph. I plot a line and two cloums of a dataframe.

```
#Line graph
x = np.linespace(0,10)
y=5x+3

#dataframe
data.plot(kind='line', x='A', y='B', ax=ax,)
```

How can i find the intersection between these two graphs?

I am very new to this forum so if i can add additional information please tell me.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766692/intersection-of-two-graphs-in-python-find-the-x-value

Comment: Thank you. I saw this post and tried it. I cant figuer out how to put in the dataframe.