# Shapely package - returning values of multiple intersections

Tags: python, shapely

courtesy of  the following answer, I am trying to extend this script to work for multiple curves...

[Intersection of two graphs in Python, find the x value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766692/intersection-of-two-graphs-in-python-find-the-x-value)

[image]

It only plots intersections on the last straigh line. Not sure how to get it for all straight lines.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString

x = np.arange(0, 1000)
f1 = np.arange(0, 500, .5)
f2 = np.arange(0, 1000)
f3 = np.arange(0, 2000, 2)
f4 = np.arange(0, 2000, 2)
f =np.stack((f1, f2, f3, f4))

g1 = np.sin(np.arange(0, 10, 0.01) * 2) * 500
g2 = np.sin(np.arange(0, 10, 0.01) * 2) * 600
g3 = np.sin(np.arange(0, 10, 0.01) * 2) * 800
g4 = np.sin(np.arange(0, 10, 0.01) * 2) * 1000
g =np.stack((g1, g2, g3, g4))
for i in range(len(f)):
    plt.plot(x, f[i])
for i in range(len(g)):
    plt.plot(x, g[i])

a = []
for i in range(len(g)):
    a.append(LineString(np.column_stack((x, g[i]))))
b = []
for i in range(len(f)):
    b.append(LineString(np.column_stack((x, f[i]))))
    
inter = []
for i in range(len(a)):
     inter.append(a[i].intersection(b[i]))

for i in range(len(inter)):
    if inter[i].geom_type == 'MultiPoint':
        plt.plot(*LineString(inter[i]).xy, 'o')
    elif inter[i].geom_type == 'Point':
        plt.plot(*inter[i].xy, 'o')
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString

x = np.arange(0, 1000)
f1 = np.arange(0, 500, .5)
f2 = np.arange(0, 1000)
f3 = np.arange(0, 2000, 2)
f4 = np.arange(0, 2000, 2)
f =np.stack((f1, f2, f3, f4))

g1 = np.sin(np.arange(0, 10, 0.01) * 2) * 500
g2 = np.sin(np.arange(0, 10, 0.01) * 2) * 600
g3 = np.sin(np.arange(0, 10, 0.01) * 2) * 800
g4 = np.sin(np.arange(0, 10, 0.01) * 2) * 1000
g =np.stack((g1, g2, g3, g4))
for i in range(len(f)):
    plt.plot(x, f[i])
for i in range(len(g)):
    plt.plot(x, g[i])

a = []
for i in range(len(g)):
    a.append(LineString(np.column_stack((x, g[i]))))
b = []
for i in range(len(f)):
    b.append(LineString(np.column_stack((x, f[i]))))
    
inter = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
     inter.append(a[i].intersection(b[j]))

for i in range(len(inter)):
    if inter[i].geom_type == 'MultiPoint':
        plt.plot(*LineString(inter[i]).xy, 'o')
    elif inter[i].geom_type == 'Point':
        plt.plot(*inter[i].xy, 'o')
```

[image]