# Draw lines perpendicular to X axis and Y axis to a curve in matplotlib plot

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a horizontal line from a selected point in Y-axis *(say, y = 150, in our following sample data*) to a curve (*blue colored straight line in our sample plot*). Then, from the point of intersection of horizontal line with the curve, I want to drop a line perpendicular to the X - axis. I tried following code line but I could not limit the value of parameter `xmax` such that the horizontal line ends exactly at the point of intersection with the curve. I also know that maximum limit of `xmax` = `1.0`. For this case, `xmax` = `0.5` may give me the point of intersection. However, I want to implement this on more complex curves. Can somebody please advise me?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.arange(10),
                   'y': np.arange(100, 200, 10)})

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(4.5,4.5))
ax.plot(df.x,df.y)

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(100,200)

# ax.axhline(y=150, xmin=-0.02, xmax=0.5, clip_on= True)
ax.axhline(y=150, xmin=0, xmax= df.loc[df['y'] == 150, 'x'].iloc[0], clip_on= False, color = 'Green')

plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

**This code generate following plot:**
[image]

**Plot I want**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766692/intersection-of-two-graphs-in-python-find-the-x-value), and the code is here.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from shapely.geometry import LineString

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.arange(10),
                   'y': np.arange(100, 200, 10)})

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(4.5,4.5))
ax.plot(df.x,df.y)

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(100,200)

ypoint = 140

### copy curve line y coords and set to a constant
lines = df.y.copy()
lines[:] = ypoint

#get intersection 
first_line = LineString(np.column_stack((df.x, df.y)))
second_line = LineString(np.column_stack((df.x, lines)))
intersection = first_line.intersection(second_line)
ax.plot(*intersection.xy, 'o')

# plot hline and vline
ax.hlines(y=ypoint, xmin=0, xmax= intersection.x, clip_on= True, color = 'Green')
ax.vlines(x=intersection.x, ymin=100, ymax= intersection.y, clip_on= True, color = 'Green')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Li Yupeng's solution is great, here is an analytic solution using scipy's `interpolate` class:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.arange(10), 'y': np.arange(100, 200, 10)})

f = interp1d(df.y, df.x)
my_y_val = 150
my_x_val = float(f(my_y_val))

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(4.5,4.5))
ax.plot(df.x,df.y)

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(100,200)

my_y_max = (my_y_val - ax.get_ylim()[0])/(ax.get_ylim()[1] - ax.get_ylim()[0])
my_x_max = (my_x_val - ax.get_xlim()[0])/(ax.get_xlim()[1] - ax.get_xlim()[0])

ax.axhline(y=my_y_val, xmin=0, xmax=my_x_max, clip_on= False, color='green')
ax.axvline(x=float(my_x_val), ymin=0, ymax=my_y_max, clip_on= False, color='blue')

plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

[image]

We create a simple linear interpolation function based on our data (reversing input and output for this case), then find the appropriate value for our given x and plot it. Note that the values for `ymax/ymin` and `xmax/xmin` are in terms of a fraction of the Axes, not values on the x- and y-axes, so we need to calculate them, allowing for an axis not starting at 0 (as is the case for one of them here).

Of course you don't need a library to implement interpolation on a straight line, but [you can swap in quadratic, linear, spline, etc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) as needed.

Comment: @ Josh thanks a lot for the help. However, I am finding difficulty in doing this in my curve. my curve is exponential defined as follows:
```def model_func(x, a, k, b):
    return a * np.exp(k*x) + b

# curve fit
p0 = (1.,1.e-5,1.) 

opt, pcov = curve_fit(model_func, df.x, df.y, p0)
a, k, b = opt
```

Comment: The code you pasted is incomplete, but I tested this with `df['y'] = np.exp(df['x'])` and it works well, even with the default linear interpolation. Note that I just fixed an error - I'd hardcoded the 150 in `axhline`.