# Plot graph with area of two data set and get probability

Tags: python, plot, plotly, fill

I am trying to plot a path of rotating rod ends as it moves forward in space. I made a vector that rotates around the centre with certain rotational speed and then move the vector to the place next place with certain translational speed. I made the whole function work with time-steps (for loop as time-step), so I can make it more accurate if want. So the result is this:
[image]

```
def rotate_vector(vector, angle):
    x = vector[0] * math.cos(angle) - vector[1] * math.sin(angle)
    y = vector[0] * math.sin(angle) + vector[1] * math.cos(angle)
    return [x, y]


fig = go.Figure()
rod_1 = np.array([0, -(1.0/2)])
rod_2 = np.array([0, (1.0/2)])
center = np.array([-0.5,0.0])
fig.update_layout(yaxis_range=[-5, 5])
fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[-2,12])
fig.update_layout(width=1000, height=500)
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
#plt.autoscale(False)
speed = 13 #m/s
rot_speed = (math.pi*2*1.5)/(11.50 -10.69) #deg/s
step_size = 0.01
rod_end_1 = {"x": [], "y": []}
rod_end_2 = {"x": [], "y": []}
for i in np.arange(0, 1, step_size): #s
   fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = [center[0] ,rod_1[0] + center[0]], y = [center[1], rod_1[1]]))
   fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = [center[0] ,rod_2[0] + center[0]], y = [center[1], rod_2[1]]))
   rod_end_1["x"].append(rod_1[0] + center[0])
   rod_end_1["y"].append(rod_1[1] + center[1])
   rod_end_2["x"].append(rod_2[0] + center[0])
   rod_end_2["y"].append(rod_2[1] + center[1])
   rod_1 = rotate_vector(rod_1, rot_speed * step_size)
   rod_2 = rotate_vector(rod_2, rot_speed * step_size)
   center[0] += step_size * speed
fig.show()
```

With this I get the paths of the rod ends.
What I want to do, is fill this whole path, but I can't get it like I want it:
[image]
I want to "fill" look like the first picture with fill, but it doesn't look like it. Here is the code with using plotly:

```
fig2 = go.Figure()
fig2.update_layout(yaxis_range=[-1, 1])
fig2.update_layout(xaxis_range=[-1,15])
fig2.update_layout(width=1000, height=500)
fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = rod_end_1["x"], y = rod_end_1["y"], fill='tonexty'))
fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = rod_end_2["x"], y = rod_end_2["y"], fill='tonexty'))
fig2.show()
```

Any good ideas how to make it look like the first one with fill?

In the end I would like to get the "probability" or precent of area covert from rods moving point of view. So in the centre it would be 100% and on the positive y-axis it would be little lower than in negative y-axis. Like Gaussian plot.

If anyone has a good idea on how to implement this, or any improvements to the code I've currently written, that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Here is an example what I'm searching:

[image]

So the area that rod covers by moving, will be filled and in the bottom there would be a present level of how much area is covered.

Comment: can you include the code you used to produce the path of the rotating rod ends? it would be helpful if we could reproduce your plot so far

Comment: Good idea. Added.

Comment: what is `rotate_vector`?

Comment: Ou, right. Added now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to plot the coordinates of one end of rod 1 in order (over time), then plot the coordinates of the other end of rod 1, then fill the area in between those two traces. Then do the same for rod 2.

Determining the probabilities is significantly more difficult as you have to find the area under the curves for the areas swept out by both rod 1 and rod 2. The code is wrote is hacky in the sense that there are hard-coded quantities and edge cases to account for, but it applies the trapezoid rule to find the area between consecutive points along each curve individually, then adds them together. I also correct for the region where rod 1 and rod 2 entirely overlap. It's not perfect, but it's about as close I can get for the time being.

```
import math
from math import isclose
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

def rotate_vector(vector, angle):
    x = vector[0] * math.cos(angle) - vector[1] * math.sin(angle)
    y = vector[0] * math.sin(angle) + vector[1] * math.cos(angle)
    return [x, y]

fig = go.Figure()
rod_1 = np.array([0, -(1.0/2)])
rod_2 = np.array([0, (1.0/2)])
center = np.array([-0.5,0.0])
fig.update_layout(yaxis_range=[-2, 13])
fig.update_layout(width=1000, height=500)
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
#plt.autoscale(False)
speed = 13 #m/s
rot_speed = (math.pi*2*1.5)/(11.50 -10.69) #deg/s
step_size = 0.01
rod_end_1 = {"x": [], "y": []}
rod_end_2 = {"x": [], "y": []}
centers = {"x": [], "y": []}
for i in np.arange(0, 1, step_size): #s
    # swap x and y coordinates
    rod_end_1["y"].append(rod_1[0] + center[0]) 
    rod_end_1["x"].append(rod_1[1] + center[1])
    rod_end_2["y"].append(rod_2[0] + center[0])
    rod_end_2["x"].append(rod_2[1] + center[1])
    rod_1 = rotate_vector(rod_1, rot_speed * step_size)
    rod_2 = rotate_vector(rod_2, rot_speed * step_size)
    center[0] += step_size * speed
    centers["y"].append(center[0])
    centers["x"].append(center[1]) # this coordinate doesn't change, but in case it does later, you'll want to store it

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

## traces for rod_1
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=rod_end_1['x'],
    y=rod_end_1['y'],
    marker=dict(color='#636EFA'),
), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=centers['x'],
    y=centers['y'],
    marker=dict(color='#636EFA'),
    fill='tonexty',
), row=1, col=1)

## traces for rod_2
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=rod_end_2['x'],
    y=rod_end_2['y'],
    marker=dict(color='#EF553B'),
), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=centers['x'],
    y=centers['y'],
    marker=dict(color='#EF553B'),
    fill='tonexty',
), row=1, col=1)

## the area curve is difficult
## the following method might not be easily generalizable 

rod_end_1['x_arr'] = np.array(rod_end_1['x'])
rod_end_1['y_arr'] = np.array(rod_end_1['y'])
rod_end_2['x_arr'] = np.array(rod_end_2['x'])
rod_end_2['y_arr'] = np.array(rod_end_2['y'])

fig.add_shape(type="line",
    x0=-0.6, y0=-0.5, x1=0.6, y1=-0.5,
    line=dict(
        width=2,
        dash="dot",
    )
)
fig.add_shape(type="line",
    x0=-0.6, y0=12, x1=0.6, y1=12,
    line=dict(
        width=2,
        dash="dot",
    )
)
fig.add_shape(type="line",
    x0=-0.5, y0=-1, x1=-0.5, y1=13,
    line=dict(
        width=2,
        dash="dot",
    )
)
fig.add_shape(type="line",
    x0=0.5, y0=-1, x1=0.5, y1=13,
    line=dict(
        width=2,
        dash="dot",
    )
)

rod_intersections = [rod_end_1['x_arr'][10], 0]

fig.add_shape(type="line",
    x0=rod_intersections[0], y0=-1, x1=rod_intersections[0], y1=13,
    line=dict(
        width=2,
        dash="dot",
    )
)


# first_intersection = rod_end_1['x'][17]
# trapezoid area formula = h(a+b)/2
bins_areas = {}
for i,x in enumerate(rod_end_1['x']):
    if isclose(rod_end_1['x'][i], 0.5):
        break
    else:
        bin_start, bin_end = rod_end_1['x'][i],rod_end_1['x'][i+1]
        bins_areas[(bin_start, bin_end)] = 0

## go through first two regions swept out by rod 1
for bin in bins_areas.keys():
    bin_start, bin_end = bin
    h = bin_end - bin_start
    start_idx = [isclose(x, bin_start) for x in rod_end_1['x_arr']]
    end_idx = [isclose(x, bin_end) for x in rod_end_1['x_arr']]
    y_vals_start = rod_end_1['y_arr'][start_idx]
    y_vals_end = rod_end_1['y_arr'][end_idx]
    if y_vals_end[0] <= 1.68915408:
        a = y_vals_start[0] - (-0.5)
        b = y_vals_end[0] - (-0.5)
    elif isclose(bin_end, 0.5):
        a = y_vals_start[1] - y_vals_start[0]
        b = 0 # we have reached a point on the other side
    else:
        a = y_vals_start[1] - y_vals_start[0]
        b = y_vals_end[1] - y_vals_end[0]
    area = h*(a+b)/2
    bins_areas[bin] += area

## go through next two regions swept out by rod 1
for bin in bins_areas.keys():
    bin_start, bin_end = bin
    h = bin_end - bin_start
    start_idx = [isclose(x, bin_start) for x in rod_end_1['x_arr']]
    end_idx = [isclose(x, bin_end) for x in rod_end_1['x_arr']]
    y_vals_start = rod_end_1['y_arr'][start_idx]
    y_vals_end = rod_end_1['y_arr'][end_idx]
    if isclose(bin_start, -0.5):
        a = 0
        b = y_vals_end[2] - y_vals_end[1]
    elif y_vals_end[0] <= 1.68915408:
        a = y_vals_start[2] - y_vals_start[1] # 3rd point up - 2nd point up
        b = y_vals_end[2] - y_vals_end[1]
    elif isclose(bin_end, 0.5):
        a = y_vals_start[3] - y_vals_start[2]
        b = 0 # we have reached a point on the other side
    else:
        a = y_vals_start[3] - y_vals_start[2] # 4th point up - 3rd point up
        b = y_vals_end[3] - y_vals_end[2]
    area = h*(a+b)/2
    bins_areas[bin] += area

## go through each area swept out by rod 2
for bin in reversed(bins_areas.keys()):
    bin_start, bin_end = bin
    h = bin_end - bin_start
    start_idx = [isclose(x, bin_start) for x in rod_end_2['x_arr']]
    end_idx = [isclose(x, bin_end) for x in rod_end_2['x_arr']]
    y_vals_start = rod_end_2['y_arr'][start_idx]
    y_vals_end = rod_end_2['y_arr'][end_idx]
    if isclose(bin_end, 0.5):
        a = y_vals_start[0] - (-0.5)
        b = 0
    elif y_vals_start[0] <= 0.82:
        a = y_vals_start[0] - (-0.5)
        b = y_vals_end[0] - (-0.5)
    elif isclose(bin_end, -0.5):
        a = 0
        b = y_vals_start[1] - y_vals_start[0] # we have reached a point on the other side
    else:
        a = y_vals_start[1] - y_vals_start[0]
        b = y_vals_end[1] - y_vals_end[0]
    area = h*(a+b)/2
    bins_areas[bin] += area

## highest two areas swept out by rod 2
for bin in reversed(bins_areas.keys()):
    bin_start, bin_end = bin
    h = bin_end - bin_start
    start_idx = [isclose(x, bin_start) for x in rod_end_2['x_arr']]
    end_idx = [isclose(x, bin_end) for x in rod_end_2['x_arr']]
    y_vals_start = rod_end_2['y_arr'][start_idx]
    y_vals_end = rod_end_2['y_arr'][end_idx]
    if isclose(bin_end, 0.5):
        a = y_vals_start[2] - y_vals_start[1]
        b = 0
    elif y_vals_start[0] <= 0.82:
        a = y_vals_start[2] - y_vals_start[1]
        b = y_vals_end[2] - y_vals_end[1]
    elif isclose(bin_start, -0.5):
        a = 0
        b = y_vals_end[3] - y_vals_end[2] # we have reached a point on the other side
    else:
        a = y_vals_start[3] - y_vals_start[2]
        b = y_vals_end[3] - y_vals_end[2]
    area = h*(a+b)/2
    bins_areas[bin] += area

for bin,area in bins_areas.items():
    bin_start, bin_end = bin
    if (bin_start >= -0.2) and (bin_start <= 0):
        bin_area_corrected = (bin_end - bin_start)*(12 - (-0.5))
        bins_areas[bin] = bin_area_corrected

bin_probabilities = {}
for bin,area in bins_areas.items():
    bin_start, bin_end = bin
    total_area = (bin_end - bin_start)*(12 - (-0.5))
    bin_probabilities[bin] = area / total_area

bin_medians = [(x1+x2)/2 for x1,x2 in bins_areas.keys()]
# custom width for bars?
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=bin_medians,
    y=list(bin_probabilities.values()),
), row=2, col=1)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis1=dict(range=[-0.6,0.6]),
    xaxis2=dict(range=[-0.6,0.6]),
    showlegend=False,
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm..not quite what I'm looking for, but near. But if you would like to calculate the coverage area (from y-axis point of view) how would you do that?

Comment: @pinq can you explain a little more what you mean (or perhaps include a drawing in your question showing the desired outcome?) do you mean that you want the entire thing as one trace (like the filled area from the end of rod 1 to the end of rod 2?)

Comment: added example picture drawing

Comment: @pinq based on your drawing, we'll want to invert the coordinates so (x,y) becomes (y,x) and then use some bins to approximate the probability distribution. i'll circle back on this later, and update my answer

Comment: since you're using step sizes of 0.01, you can use a trapezoid based method of integration to determine the area between the curves in the vertical direction, but this is fairly involved. i'll see what i can come up with

Comment: The invert part( (x,y)-> (y,x) ) is irrelevant. That is a small thing to do. I just draw it that way, so it is easy to understand what I'm saying. The probability plot can even be in different window, it doesn't matter. Still hardest part is to define, the area that the rod will cover when moving and then also get the probability. I been trying to find some example where you can get the area that the object covers, but so far no luck...

Comment: the invert part matters in the sense that it determines the direction of integration for area. it's probably easiest to invert the coordinates, then integrate in the x direction, from -0.5 to 0.5 for each curve, then sum all the areas together

Comment: @pinq- i have updated the answer to include an approximate probability plot, determined by summing up the areas over red and blue regions using the trapezoid rule

Comment: So I did look in to your code and wow, you have done a lot of work. Nice and the plot is like I wanted. I even learned this new thing called trapezoid ( nice thing). But...it is over complicated ( for me at least). And there is hardcoded limits that don't a do not allow flexibility. The result is right and I will accept this, but I will also post my own result.

Answer (score 1):

So the plot window was easy to make but the probability calculation was not so easy ( at first). To make it easier I split the data in to positive and negative values so it is easier to handle ( this was my eureka moment in the shower)

```
fig_vec = make_subplots(
    rows = 2,
    cols = 3,
    specs = [[{}, {}, {}],
           [{"colspan": 3}, None, None]])
fig_vec.update_layout(width = 500, height = 1000)
fig_vec.update_layout(showlegend = False)

rod_l = 1.0
start_pos = [
        -0.5, # x
        0.0 # y
        ]
step_size = 0.001
roatation_rounds = 2
speed = 13 # m/s
rot_speed = (math.pi * 2 * roatation_rounds) / (11.50 - 10.69) #deg/s

rod_max = {"x":[], "y":[]}
rod_min = {"x":[], "y":[]}
center = np.array(start_pos)
full_rod = np.array([
    [0, -(rod_l / 2)],
    [0, rod_l / 2]
    ])

for i in np.arange(0, 0.405+step_size, step_size): #s
    # reset max and min values
    rod_max_i = [0, 0]
    rod_min_i = [0, 0]

    fig_vec.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        y = [center[0], 
             full_rod[0][0] + center[0]
            ], 
        x = [center[1],
             full_rod[0][1]
            ],
        mode = 'lines')
        , row = 1, col = 1
        )
    fig_vec.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        y = [center[0], 
             full_rod[1][0] + center[0]], 
        x = [center[1],
             full_rod[1][1]
            ],
       mode = 'lines')
        , row = 1, col = 1
        )

    for rod_end in full_rod:
        if rod_max_i[1] < rod_end[1]:
                    rod_max_i = rod_end[::]
        if rod_min_i[1] > rod_end[1]:
                    rod_min_i = rod_end[::]
    rod_max["x"].append(rod_max_i[0] + center[0])
    rod_max["y"].append(rod_max_i[1] + center[1])
    rod_min["x"].append(rod_min_i[0] + center[0])
    rod_min["y"].append(rod_min_i[1] + center[1])
    #rotate rod
    full_rod[0] = rotate_vector(full_rod[0], rot_speed * step_size)
    full_rod[1] = rotate_vector(full_rod[1], rot_speed * step_size)
    # move rod
    center[0] += step_size * speed
fig_vec.add_trace(go.Scatter(
y = rod_max["x"],
x = rod_max["y"]), 
row = 1, col = 2            
)
fig_vec.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    y = rod_min["x"],
    x = rod_min["y"],
    fill='tonexty'),
    row = 1, col = 2
    )
fig_vec.show()
```

[image]

Then I draw a line from start to end and find out where it crosses the data line and then sum all the lines are inside of the area. There is on part, where rod covers twice(triangle area) so I added that up, so "probability" will be over 100% in that area.

```
y_val       = -0.1
sample_rate = 50

y_max = rod_max["y"]
y_min = rod_min["y"]
area_covert = {}

fig_vec.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        y = rod_max["x"],
        x = rod_max["y"]),
    row = 1, col = 3)
fig_vec.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        y = rod_min["x"], 
        x = rod_min["y"]),
    row = 1, col = 3)

x = np.array(rod_max["x"])
for y_tick_pos in np.linspace(0, 0.5, num = sample_rate):
    y_line_pos = np.full(len(x), y_tick_pos)
    hit_points_pos = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(y_line_pos - y_max))).flatten() # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766692/how-to-find-the-intersection-of-two-graphs

    start_point = [x[0], y_tick_pos]
    next_point = start_point[::]
    line_color = -1
    area_covert[y_tick_pos] = 0
    for cut_point in hit_points_pos:
        next_point = [x[cut_point], y_line_pos[cut_point]]
        color_list = [255 * (( 1 + line_color) / 2), 255 * ((1 + line_color * -1) / 2)]
        fig_vec.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                y = [start_point[0], next_point[0]],
                x = [start_point[1], next_point[1]],
                mode = 'lines',
                line = dict(color = 'rgb(0.0, ' + str(color_list[0]) + ',' + str(color_list[1]) + ')' )
                ),
            row = 1, col = 3)
        if line_color == -1: # sum up all the covert areas
            area_covert[y_tick_pos] += next_point[0] - start_point[0]
        start_point = next_point[::]
        line_color *= -1

    if line_color == -1:
        area_covert[y_tick_pos] += rod_max["x"][-1] - next_point[0]
    color_list = [255 * (( 1 + line_color) / 2), 255 * ((1 + line_color * -1) / 2)]
    fig_vec.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                y = [start_point[0], rod_max["x"][-1]],
                x = [start_point[1], y_tick_pos],
                mode = 'lines',
                line = dict(color = 'rgb(0.0, ' + str(color_list[0]) + ',' + str(color_list[1]) + ')' )
                ),
            row = 1, col = 3)

x = np.array(rod_min["x"])
for y_tick_neg in np.linspace(0, -0.5, num = sample_rate):
    y_line_neg = np.full(len(x), y_tick_neg)
    hit_points_neg = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(y_line_neg - y_min))).flatten()

    start_point = [x[0], y_tick_neg]
    next_point = start_point[::]
    line_color = -1
    area_covert[y_tick_neg] = 0
    for idx_i, cut_point in enumerate(hit_points_neg):

        if cut_point != hit_points_neg[-1] and x[cut_point] > x[hit_points_neg[idx_i + 1]]: # if the line is inside 
            next_point = [x[hit_points_neg[idx_i + 1]], y_line_neg[hit_points_neg[idx_i + 1]]]
            area_covert[y_tick_neg] += x[cut_point] - x[hit_points_neg[idx_i + 1]]
        else:
            next_point = [x[cut_point], y_line_neg[cut_point]]
        color_list = [255 * (( 1 + line_color) / 2), 255 * ((1 + line_color * -1) / 2)]
        fig_vec.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                y = [start_point[0], next_point[0]],
                x = [start_point[1], next_point[1]],
                mode = 'lines',
                line = dict(color = 'rgb(0.0, ' + str(color_list[0]) + ',' + str(color_list[1]) + ')' )
                ),
            row = 1, col = 3)
        if line_color == -1:
            area_covert[y_tick_neg] += next_point[0] - start_point[0]
        start_point = next_point[::]
        line_color *= -1

    if line_color == -1:
        area_covert[y_tick_neg] +=  rod_min["x"][-1] - next_point[0]
    color_list = [255 * (( 1 + line_color) / 2), 255 * ((1 + line_color * -1) / 2)]
    fig_vec.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                y = [start_point[0], rod_min["x"][-1]],
                x = [start_point[1], y_tick_neg],
                mode = 'lines',
                line = dict(color = 'rgb(0.0, ' + str(color_list[0]) + ',' + str(color_list[1]) + ')' )
                ),
            row = 1, col = 3)

fig_vec.show()
```

[image]

And in the end I just plotted the probability graph.

```
lists = sorted(area_covert.items()) # sorted by key, return a list of tuples

propa_x, propa_y = zip(*lists) # unpack a list of pairs into two tuples
propa_y = [(y_i / area_covert[0.0]) * 100 for y_i in propa_y][::] # turn it to percent
fig_vec.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x = propa_x,
                y = propa_y,
                mode = 'lines',
                ),
            row = 2, col = 1)
fig_vec.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this is very nice, and gets around hardcoded points of intersection when integrating the area.... good stuff!