# Plot two gaussian distributions out of the data using gaussian mixture model (not a repeated question)

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, data-fitting, gaussian-mixture-model

I am having the same problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990467/fit-mixture-of-two-gaussian-normal-distributions-to-a-histogram-from-one-set-of). I followed @B.M.'s code. However, I am not able to figure out how to fit two gaussian distributions in my data. When I hist-plot it and superimpose it with the KDE, I obtain the second peak like this:

Second peak detected by the slight bump at ~0.07 units
[image]

Here are my efforts so far:

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#data=concatenate((normal(1,.2,5000),normal(2,.2,2500)))
data = pd.read_csv('gmm_outdata_ngc2173.csv')
gmm_3 = data['col3']
y,x,_=hist(gmm_3,22,alpha=.3,label='data')

x=(x[1:]+x[:-1])/2 # for len(x)==len(y)

def gauss(x,mu,sigma,A):
    return A*exp(-(x-mu)**2/2/sigma**2)

def bimodal(x,mu1,sigma1,A1,mu2,sigma2,A2):
    return gauss(x,mu1,sigma1,A1)+gauss(x,mu2,sigma2,A2)

expected=(-0.15,.02,22,0.15,.02,22)
params,cov=curve_fit(bimodal,x,y,expected)
sigma=sqrt(diag(cov))
plot(x,bimodal(x,*params),color='red',lw=3,label='model')
legend()
print(params,'\n',sigma)
```

Here is the output plot:

Output plot of fitting two Gaussian Distributions within the same dataset
[image]

Here's the behaviour I'm expecting, a bimodal behaviour from emcee and mpfit implementation.
Plot with emcee and mpfit
[image]

Any idea why that might be happening?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Based on Mr. T's helpful suggestions, I have the following result:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

np.random.seed(123)
#data=np.concatenate((np.random.normal(1, .2, 5000), np.random.normal(1.6, .3, 2500)))
data = pd.read_csv('gmm_outdata_ngc2173.csv')
gmm_3 = data['col3']
y,x,_=plt.hist(gmm_3, 22, alpha=.3, label='data')
x=(x[1:]+x[:-1])/2 # for len(x)==len(y)
#%%
def gauss(x, mu, sigma, A):
    return A*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/2/sigma**2)

def bimodal(x, mu1, sigma1, A1, mu2, sigma2, A2):
    return gauss(x,mu1,sigma1,A1)+gauss(x,mu2,sigma2,A2)

#expected = (1, .2, 250, 2, .2, 125)
expected=(-0.15,.02,22,0.15,.02,22)
params, cov = curve_fit(bimodal, x, y, expected)
sigma=np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))
x_fit = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 500)
plt.plot(x_fit, bimodal(x_fit, *params), color='red', lw=3, label='model')
plt.plot(x_fit, gauss(x_fit, *params[:3]), color='red', lw=1, ls="--", label='distribution 1')
plt.plot(x_fit, gauss(x_fit, *params[3:]), color='red', lw=1, ls=":", label='distribution 2')
plt.legend()
#print(pd.DataFrame(data={'params': params, 'sigma': sigma}, index=bimodal.__code__.co_varnames[1:]))
plt.show()
```

When I try to change "*params[3:]", I get an error gauss() missing 1 required positional argument: 'A'.
[Mr. T's code's output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDsSG.png)
Edit 2:

I am uploading the data I am working on. Please have a look [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OO0Ol614klmnsXMJ3gfwh6SzmSYPvbh2/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: What is the behaviour you expect?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I have added the part of expected behaviour in my question. I want to show the bimodality which is present in the data I obtain from the Gaussian mixture modelling (gmm). The gmm code I'm using successfully detects the second peak, I only want to display two Gaussian distributions on the same data set. Please let me know if you have any ideas or suggestions. Thanks so much!

Comment: So, your problem is that your graph doesn't show the separate Gaussian components? I mean, your output obviously has two peaks.

Comment: As an aside: [Don't use pylab](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html#module-pylab), [dont' use `import *`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad).

Comment: @Mr. T Yes, that's exactly my problem.

Thanks for the tip for not using pylab and not importing *.

Comment: As I see quite often references to the answer you lifted your code from, I have [rewritten the code without pylab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70907042/8881141) and added the two distributions. Just for you.

Comment: This is exactly, what I wanted. Let me try it for my dataset, and get back to you. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question with my latest trials (from @Mr.T T's suggestions.). I have also uploaded the dataset I am working on. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Curve fitting is often sensitive to changes in start values. In a histogram, you get a good idea of the mean values and amplitudes of the two peaks, and we should make use of it. We should also restrict sigma values and amplitudes to nonnegative values:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = np.genfromtxt("test.csv", skip_header=True)

y,x,_=plt.hist(data, 22, alpha=.3,label='data')
x=(x[1:]+x[:-1])/2 

def gauss(x, mu, sigma, A):
    return A*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/2/sigma**2)

def bimodal(x, mu1, sigma1, A1, mu2, sigma2, A2):
    return gauss(x, mu1, sigma1, A1)+gauss(x, mu2, sigma2, A2)

expected = (0, .01, 20, .1, .01, 5)
params, cov = curve_fit(bimodal, x, y, expected, 
                        #[[lower], [upper]] bounds for mu1, sigma1, A1, mu2, sigma2, A2
                        bounds=[[-np.inf, 0, 0, -np.inf, 0, 0], [np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf]]) 
sigma=np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))
x_fit = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 500)
plt.plot(x_fit, bimodal(x_fit, *params), color='red', lw=3, label='model')
plt.plot(x_fit, gauss(x_fit, *params[:3]), color='red', lw=1, ls="--", label='distribution 1')
plt.plot(x_fit, gauss(x_fit, *params[3:]), color='red', lw=1, ls=":", label='distribution 2')
plt.legend()
print(pd.DataFrame(data={'params': params, 'sigma': sigma}, index=bimodal.__code__.co_varnames[1:]))
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
           params     sigma
mu1      0.003198  0.005179
sigma1   0.042710  0.005658
A1      18.119693  1.840331
mu2      0.097203  0.009387
sigma2   0.010044  0.007779
A2       5.346416  3.519740
```

[image]