# Intersection between Gaussian

Tags: python, gaussian

I'm just trying to plot two gaussians and to find the intersection point. I have the following code. It's not plotting the exact intersection though and I really cannot figure out why. It's like just barely slightly off but I worked through the derived solution if we took the log of subtracted gaussians and yeah it seems like it should be correct. Can anyone help? Thank you so much!

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def plot_normal(x, mean = 0, sigma = 1):
    return 1.0/(2*np.pi*sigma**2) * np.exp(-((x-mean)**2)/(2*sigma**2))

# found online
def solve_gasussians(m1, s1, m2, s2):
  a = 1.0/(2.0*s1**2) - 1.0/(2.0*s2**2)
  b = m2/(s2**2) - m1/(s1**2)
  c = m1**2 /(2*s1**2) - m2**2 / (2.0*s2**2) - np.log(s2/s1)
  return np.roots([a,b,c])

s1 = np.linspace(0, 10,300)
s2 = np.linspace(0, 14, 300)

solved_val = solve_gasussians(5.0, 0.5, 7.0, 1.0)
print solved_val
solved_val = solved_val[0]
plt.figure('Baseline Distributions')
plt.title('Baseline Distributions')
plt.xlabel('Response Rate')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.plot(s1, plot_normal(s1, 5.0, 0.5),'r', label='s1')
plt.plot(s2, plot_normal(s2, 7.0, 1.0),'b', label='s2')
plt.plot(solved_val, plot_normal(solved_val, 7.0, 1.0), 'mo')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you point us to the solution you found online so that we don't have to try to derive it for ourselves?

Comment: I think the solution they're referring to may be this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22579904/752843). So we can't entirely blame them for an atrocious lack of commenting in the code.

Comment: @Richard, that's what I think too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small bug in `plot_normal` function - you are missing square root in the denominator. Proper version:

```
def plot_normal(x, mean = 0, sigma = 1):
    return 1.0/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma**2) * np.exp(-((x-mean)**2)/(2*sigma**2))
```

gives the expected result:
[image]

And two remarks.

1. Remember that you can have 2 roots of the equation in general (two intersection points), and this is the case with parameters you provided.
2. As far as I know `np.roots` gives you approximate result, but you cat get exact result easily, rewriting `solve_gasussians` function as:

   ```
   def solve_gasussians(m1, s1, m2, s2):
       # coefficients of quadratic equation ax^2 + bx + c = 0
       a = (s1**2.0) - (s2**2.0)
       b = 2 * (m1 * s2**2.0 - m2 * s1**2.0)
       c = m2**2.0 * s1**2.0 - m1**2.0 * s2**2.0 - 2 * s1**2.0 * s2**2.0 * np.log(s1/s2)
       x1 = (-b + np.sqrt(b**2.0 - 4.0 * a * c)) / (2.0 * a)
       x2 = (-b - np.sqrt(b**2.0 - 4.0 * a * c)) / (2.0 * a)
       return x1, x2
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the mistake lies in your code. But I think I found the code your borrowed from and made part of the adjustment you need.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.stats import norm

def solve(m1,m2,std1,std2):
  a = 1/(2*std1**2) - 1/(2*std2**2)
  b = m2/(std2**2) - m1/(std1**2)
  c = m1**2 /(2*std1**2) - m2**2 / (2*std2**2) - np.log(std2/std1)
  return np.roots([a,b,c])

m1 = 5
std1 = 0.5
m2 = 7
std2 = 1

result = solve(m1,m2,std1,std2)

x = np.linspace(-5,9,10000)
plot1=plt.plot(x,[norm.pdf(_,m1,std1) for _ in x])
plot2=plt.plot(x,[norm.pdf(_,m2,std2) for _ in x])
plot3=plt.plot(result[0],norm.pdf(result[0],m1,std1) ,'o')

plt.show()
```

I will offer two pieces of unsolicited advice that might make life easier for you (in the way they do for me):

- When you adapt code try to make small, incremental changes and check that the code still works at each step.
- Look for existing free libraries. In this case **norm** from scipy is a good replacement for what was used in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is here. This line:

```
def plot_normal(x, mean = 0, sigma = 1):
  return 1.0/(2*np.pi*sigma**2) * np.exp(-((x-mean)**2)/(2*sigma**2))
```

Should be this:

```
def plot_normal(x, mean = 0, sigma = 1):
  return 1.0/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma**2) * np.exp(-((x-mean)**2)/(2*sigma**2))
```

You forgot the `sqrt`.

It would be wiser to use a pre-existing normal pdf if that's available, such as:

```
import scipy.stats
def plot_normal(x, mean = 0, sigma = 1):
  return scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x,loc=mean,scale=sigma)
```

It's also possible to solve for the intersections exactly. [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12213/12116) provides a quadratic equation for the roots of the Gaussians' intersections. Using maxima to solve for x gives the following expression. Which, while complicated, does not rely on iterative methods and can be automatically generated from simpler expressions.

```
def solve_gaussians(m1,s1,m2,s2):
  x1 = (s1*s2*np.sqrt((-2*np.log(s1/s2)*s2**2)+2*s1**2*np.log(s1/s2)+m2**2-2*m1*m2+m1**2)+m1*s2**2-m2*s1**2)/(s2**2-s1**2)
  x2 = -(s1*s2*np.sqrt((-2*np.log(s1/s2)*s2**2)+2*s1**2*np.log(s1/s2)+m2**2-2*m1*m2+m1**2)-m1*s2**2+m2*s1**2)/(s2**2-s1**2)
  return x1,x2
```

Putting it altogether gives:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import scipy.stats

def plot_normal(x, mean = 0, sigma = 1):
  return scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x,loc=mean,scale=sigma)

#Use the equation from [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12213/12116) solved for x
def solve_gaussians(m1,s1,m2,s2):
  x1 = (s1*s2*np.sqrt((-2*np.log(s1/s2)*s2**2)+2*s1**2*np.log(s1/s2)+m2**2-2*m1*m2+m1**2)+m1*s2**2-m2*s1**2)/(s2**2-s1**2)
  x2 = -(s1*s2*np.sqrt((-2*np.log(s1/s2)*s2**2)+2*s1**2*np.log(s1/s2)+m2**2-2*m1*m2+m1**2)-m1*s2**2+m2*s1**2)/(s2**2-s1**2)
  return x1,x2

s = np.linspace(0, 14,300)
x = solve_gaussians(5.0,0.5,7.0,1.0)

plt.figure('Baseline Distributions')
plt.title('Baseline Distributions')
plt.xlabel('Response Rate')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.plot(s, plot_normal(s, 5.0, 0.5),'r', label='s1')
plt.plot(s, plot_normal(s, 7.0, 1.0),'b', label='s2')
plt.plot(x[0],plot_normal(x[0],5.,0.5),'mo')
plt.plot(x[1],plot_normal(x[1],5.,0.5),'mo')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Giving:

[image: Intersection of Gaussians]