# Pyplot Histogram - Get the exact x values from the automatic bins

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have two data arrays for which I plot a histogram using pyplot:

```
data1 = numpyArray1
data2 = numpyArray2
```

They do not have the same size, so I use the option `density=True` to compare them properly. I'm also letting pyplot select the bins automatically, as the data is float and I'm not (unless it's absolutely necessary) creating the limits automatically.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(....)
ax[...].hist([data1, data2], bins = 30, density = True, histtype='step)
```

Example:

[image: plot]

**Questions:**

1. Can I assume that the bins are exactly the same for both distributions?
2. How can I see (or even better, get) the automatic bin limits that pyplot created? ([This question assumes the bins are integer numbers, not valid for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083051/matplotlib-xticks-not-lining-up-with-histogram))
3. (optinal) Can I get the intersection point of the two curves somehow? ([This question assumes gaussian distribution, which doesn't solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579434/python-finding-the-intersection-point-of-two-gaussian-curves))

Comment: In your code above you are passing 30 bins. The default value of bins is 10 as per [this](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#matplotlib-rcparams) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html), `hist` will return

> n : array or list of array. The values of the histogram bins.
>
> bins : The edges of the bins.
>
> patches : Silent list of individual patches used to create the histogram or list of such list if multiple input datasets.

So use:

```
freqs, bins, _ = ax[...].hist([data1, data2], bins = 30, density = True, histtype='step)
```

**In answer to your questions**:

> Can I assume that the bins are exactly the same for both distributions?

Yes, as they are returned in the same call

> How can I see (or even better, get) the automatic bin limits that pyplot created? (This question assumes the bins are integer numbers, not valid for me)

with `bins` (see code)

> (optinal) Can I get the intersection point of the two curves somehow? (This question assumes gaussian distribution, which doesn't solve my problem)

Get the frequencies and normalize them, then see when one crosses the other. Example (with `freq` defined as above):

```
freqA, freqB = freq
freqA /= freqA.sum()
freqB /= freqB.sum()
ix = np.diff(np.sign(f[0] - f[1])).nonzero()   # check where sign changes (curves cross)
intersections = (bins[ix] + bins[ix + 1]) / 2
```

Comment: Thank you :) -- Do you know what patches are?

Comment: They are `matplotlib.pyplot` objects (https://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html ), you can use them to access custom properties to, say, change the color of one of the bars. But most of the times you won't use them at all.